# Seeking Stack Exchange site to post questions regarding using company services like Google?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

Is there a platform on stack exchange I can post questions regarding using company services like Google?

I'm specifically looking to download my Google activity and have some questions regarding this, to which I have not found answers online.

Comment: How is google a company service? Are you talking about gmail or google docs or something like that? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: The company is Google the services are Gmail Google docs... I'm specifically looking to download my Google activity and have some questions regarding this, to which I have not found answers online.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander Add that information to your question please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! There is! It’s the [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) site. As explained in [the help center for that site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> ### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> **Web Applications Stack Exchange** is for expert and advanced users of web applications.
>
> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which **behaves like an application**
> - Features of browsers which are **directly** related to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!